# Python strings in a Cython extension type

Tags: python, cython

I have an extension type (`cdef class`) with a string field. I don't know what's the best way of declaring it. Assume the following code:

```
cdef class Box:
    cdef char *_s
    cdef public str s1
    cdef public bytes s2

    property s:
        def __get__(self):
            cdef bytes py_string = self._s
            return py_string

    def __init__(self, s):
        cdef char *aux = s
        self._s = aux
        self.s1 = s
        self.s2 = s
```

And using the extension type:

```
>>> import test as t
>>> b = t.Box("hello")
>>> b.s
'hello!'
>>> b.s1
'hello'
>>> b.s2
'hello'
>>> type(b.s)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(b.s1)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(b.s2)
<type 'str'>
```

They all work, but I'm not sure about issues like garbage collection and the lifetime of the string objects. I don't like the `char *` + property approach since it's the most inefficient of the three.

So my question is: what's the best way of doing this? Is using `cdef public str s` safe?

EDIT:

Well `cdef public str s` seems to work fine as long as a reference to the `Box` is held somewhere.

```
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.is_tracked(b)
True
>>> gc.get_referrers(b.s1)
[<test.Box object at 0x1a4f680>]
>>> gc.get_referrers(b.s2)
[<test.Box object at 0x1a4f680>]
>>> b.s1
'hello'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I find it often very helpful to inspect the generated c/c++ code. So you see what's happening behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have concerns about the garbage collection of the string.

If that strings comes from another C-space program then just copy its value, so that the Box object owns it.

Comment: The string comes from Python space and it has to be stored in C space.